# URL Rewrite for CPT single posts

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, rewrite-rules, rewrite-tag

I'm struggling with Wordpress' rewrite function

I have the following URL structure

```
http://example.com/album/test-7/
```

'album' is the slug for the CPT single page
'test-7' is the slug for the CPT post

I'm trying to create a rewrite to allow a URL like

```
http://example.com/album/test-7/page/2
```

I'm using `paginate_links()` to create these links but when you visit a link with the desired structure the URL reverts to

```
http://example.com/album/test-7/
```

I've tried adding a URL tag and rewrite, but I'm very bad with both of these, here's what I have:

```
add_rewrite_tag('%paged%','([^&]+)');

add_rewrite_rule('^album/([a-z])/([0-9]{1,})?','index.php?p=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]','top');
```

I'm not sure if I'm way off or close to getting it, but this would help clear up rewrite situations involving CPT ID's and pagination variables.

Comment: pagination exists for single cpt posts in the form `http://example.com/album/test-7/2/`

Comment: Is there a pre-existing variable for this?

Comment: single post pagination query var is `page`, archive pagination is `paged`.